# Laptop not connecting to TV via HDMI

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi

I have a Dell Vostro 3400 (Windows 7) that has stopped displaying on Toshiba TV. When I plug the cable in, the laptop flashes black a few times but then the TV says `No video signal.` I know it's not the HDMI cord as this exact set-up worked a few weeks ago. My laptop had a `Nvidia Geforce 310M, 512MB Hybrid Graphics Vostro` card installed when I bought it but I cannot seem to find any reference to this in the Display Adapters. It only shows `Intel(R) HD Graphics` and `Standard VGA Graphics Adapter` with a Code 10. How can I get it to connect? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Has anything else changed since it worked? Did you move, do updates, change any hardware, install software, etc? Do you have access to another tv/cable setup to make sure its in tour computer specifically? Not saying the cable is to blame, but just because it worked a few weeks ago doesn't really exclude it from being the cause, just a thought.

Comment: Everything is the same as far as I know. No new updates other than installing Eclipse. Cable works on another computer and in the Intel Graphics and Media Control Panel it recognizes the Toshiba display and I have it set cloning the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming none of these are broken/faulty:

- TV
- HDMI cord
- laptop/graphics card

I would suggest you plug it up again, the press Windows Key + P. This controls the "projector mode." Check out [this link](http://forums.pcpitstop.com/index.php?/topic/191946-windows-key-p-easy-display-switcher/) for more info. Press the Windows Key + P to bring up the menu, then use arrow keys and enter key to select what you want.